# VS2015 resource editor never lets me save anything. WTF, how to save anything?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, embedded-resource

I'm working in Visual Studio 2015 C++, but I get the same behavior in VS 2013, and VS 2017: I have a VS Solution with multiple build targets. Some targets are libs, some are applications. All the applications have a .rc file, but none of the resources can be saved. I can modify them in the resource editor, but any changes cannot be saved. Any individual resources changed triggers a dialog asking to save that resource to a new file in a non-existing path, and that "save" can never be resolved - creating the path, or whatnot does not help.

Comment: Is the resource file read only? Or maybe a permissions issue on the folder?

Comment: the application.rc file is not read only. And the application's project directory is not read only. Are you referring to some other folder?

Comment: I meant the folder containing the `.rc` file.

Comment: The .rc file is inside the application's build directory, along with the other Visual Studio created project and solution files.The entire project for the application in question is in one directory, with sub-directories for the Debug and Release, but all sources, headers, the one .rc file and the IDE files are together.